# UV4L MJPEG stream gets stuck after a while

Tags: camera, streaming-video, uv4l

I'm using UV4L HTTP server for MJPEG video streaming from Raspberry Pi Model B v2.

I've followed this manual, [How to install or upgrade UV4L on Raspbian Wheezy & Raspbian Jessie (for Raspberry Pi)](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14]), to set it up. It's working and it's great, except the stream gets stuck after a while. Page refresh is enough to get it going again, but I want to solve the problem that causes the video stream to stop. This happens both to RPi camera v1.3 and RPi camera v2.

I've checked `dmesg` and `syslog` for relevant errors, but haven't found anything. Googling did not produce any significant result.

Where I can find more info about the problem and how can I solve it? Have you ever encountered it?

---

**Updates**

I was able to make it go for almost a day, by attaching client to the same switch in LAN, setting limit to session number and adding a keep-alive to the socket. However. I want to diagnose the problem at it's root. Is there a way to get an UV4L log, to figure out what causes the stream to halt? Or maybe it's browser's fault?

Comment: try different browsers to see if it depends on the browser, make sure you have enough bandwidth, mjpeg is quite heavy compared to h264, decrease the resolution and jpeg quality and try again.

Comment: I've attached Raspberry and the client to the save switch via LAN (first there was a Wi-Fi access point in the middle). I've also enabled keep-alive and limited number of sessions to 1. 10 hours and going well.

Comment: In fact, the bandwidth is also an important consideration. Reducing from 1080p to 720p removed any delay (I think especially effective together with better RPI-to-client connection).